# java.io.NotSerializableException while writing to Oracle Coherence cache

Tags: preloading, oracle-coherence, notserializableexception

I have 2 storage enabled cache nodes that i am trying to use for pre-loading of cache. About 1 million accounts are to be loaded by these 2 storage enabled nodes. Both key and value are `String` objects which I am trying to write to cache. I am using `InvocationService.execute()` method to invoke the pre-loading tasks asynchronously:

```java
for (Map.Entry<Member, LoaderInvocable> entry : mappedWork.entrySet()) {
    Member member = entry.getKey();
    LoaderInvocable task = entry.getValue();
    invocationService.execute(task, Collections.singleton(member), null);
}
```

`LoaderInvocable` is a class that is implementing `Invocable` and `Serializable` interfaces and its `run()` method has been overridden to performs the actual work of reading from database and writing to the cache.

`InvocationService` is defined as below in the coherence config file:

```xml
<invocation-scheme>
      <scheme-name>
      InvocationScheme</scheme-name>
      <service-name>
      LoaderInvocationService</service-name>
      <autostart system-property="tangosol.coherence.invocation.autostart">true</autostart>
 </invocation-scheme>
```

Below is the exception that i am getting:

```
2016-02-22 17:16:24,612 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR (support.context.SessionExecutable) Caught exception from SessionExecutable.execute()
(Wrapped) java.io.NotSerializableException: com.oracle.common.collections.ConcurrentLinkedQueue
    at com.tangosol.util.Base.ensureRuntimeException(Base.java:289)
    at com.tangosol.util.Base.ensureRuntimeException(Base.java:270)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketPublisher.packetizeMessage(PacketPublisher.CDB:28)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketPublisher$InQueue.add(PacketPublisher.CDB:8)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketPublisher.post(PacketPublisher.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.Message.dispatch(Message.CDB:77)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.Message.post(Message.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.post(Grid.CDB:2)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.send(Grid.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.InvocationService.execute(InvocationService.CDB:33)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.safeService.SafeInvocationService.execute(SafeInvocationService.CDB:1)
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.oracle.common.collections.ConcurrentLinkedQueue
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.Hashtable.writeObject(Hashtable.java:988)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.Component.writeObject(Component.CDB:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.Component.writeObject(Component.CDB:1)
```

It seems that half of the accounts have been cached successfully. Can it be node specific issue? Both of the storage enabled cache nodes are on the same server using the same cluster configuration. From the logs it is clear that both nodes successfully joined the cluster.

Comment: Even on the same server, the invocable is going to travel over the network from 1 node to the other and therefore needs to be serializable.

Comment: My LoaderInvocable class is already Serializable, Paul. Still getting the error. Even the objects that i am storing in the cache, is String only which is implicitly serializable.

Comment: Please check your LoaderInvocable class implements PofSerializer

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I have used the POF serializer and not facing the exception anymore. But now i am facing a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Praveen. I have implemented the `PortableObject` interface and not facing the `NotSerializableException` anymore. But now i am facing a new problem. The second node is not invoking the task and leaving the cluster without any exception in the logs.

I used the `InvocationObserver` which suggests that `memberLeft()` the cluster. Can it be something wrong with my implementation of `readExternal()` and `writeExternal()` methods for serialization? Below is the implementation:

```java
@Override
public void readExternal(PofReader paramPofReader) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    cacheName = paramPofReader.readString(0);
    firstRow = paramPofReader.readLong(1);
    lastRow = paramPofReader.readLong(2);

}

@Override
public void writeExternal(PofWriter paramPofWriter) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    paramPofWriter.writeString(0, cacheName);
    paramPofWriter.writeLong(1, firstRow);
    paramPofWriter.writeLong(2, lastRow);
}
```